# How to buffer only selected set of items from an observable source and emit other items immediately?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

For example, I have an observable that emits a number each second. I want to buffer them into arrays for a period of 4 seconds. But when the source emits a number that is divisible by 5, I want to emit it immediately and not buffer it.

```
// emit value in sequence every 1 second
// 0,1,2,3,4,5...
const source = interval(1000);

// buffer values for 4 seconds
const buffered = source.pipe(
  buffer(interval(4000)),
  filter(x => x.length > 0)  
);

const subscribe = buffered.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

My expected result is:

```
[0,1,2,3] // buffered and emitted after 4 seconds
[5] // emitted immediately
[4,6,7,8] // buffered and emitted after 4 seconds
[10] // emitted immediately
[9,11,12,13]
// ... and so on
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cdvc2d?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having two observables with the two different responsibilities and then merge them together?

```
const source = interval(1000);

// buffer values for 4 seconds
const buffered = source.pipe(
  buffer(interval(4000)),
  filter(x => x.length > 0)  
);

const multipleOfFive = source.pipe(
  filter(x => x % 5 === 0)
);

const subscribe = merge(buffered, multipleOfFive).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I am not sure whether you would also like to filter the multiples of 5 in the first observable, but that would be easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multicast` to split the source stream into two and then merge them again with different `filter` operators.

```
import { of, interval, Subject, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferTime, multicast, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

const buffered = source.pipe(
  multicast(new Subject(), s => merge(
    s.pipe(
      filter((value: number) => value % 5 === 0),
    ),
    s.pipe(
      filter((value: number) => value % 5 !== 0),
      bufferTime(4000),
    ),
  ))
);
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sbhn8s?file=index.ts